# website code disturbed while hosting on AWS

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have a wordpress website which is built on a LAMP stack. We have recently moved our website from Godaddy to AWS platform and since the move, my website is not functioning correctly. Here are the kind of issues we are facing after we moved to AWS.

1. The website custom login/sign up box has gone and users and we are getting the wordpress default login box instead.
2. The sign up to the website is not happening because the registration box is the showing strange fields( email, password, username, first name, last name, email again, and a message that we will mail you a password, which doesn't make sense)
3. The website is a crowd sourced portal so we had a customised CMS system on the website, but  the CMS editor in which users create articles is not working fine as it destroys all formatting.
4. Other similar issues which are making the site look totally shabby and dysfunctional.

I'd be glad if someone could tell me here if we did something wrongly while moving the website. What's the fastes, best way to restore all Site functionalities now.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that AWS is the issue here.

What is possible though, is that during the move a file may have become corrupt (or not fully transferred).  If you're having lots of temperamental issues throughout the site, such as the ones you're describing, it sounds like it may be a JavaScript error.

If a JS file that is included on every page didn't transfer properly then this could very well cause the issues you're having.  If you open your JavaScript Console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J` in Chrome) when you're on one of the problematic pages then you should be able to identify any potential JS errors.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. There are also strange widgets appearing ont he website, like Home Widget 0. Could this also be related to a JS file like you mentiones?